# Android real time graph adjustments user touch screen

Tags: android, real-time, graphing

Is there any existing graphing library for android that will allow me to draw a line with an adjustable amount of segments that can be touched and dragged in real time? I currently have a working application using androidplot that captures an image of what I'm scanning and graphs that data. I need adjustable line segment under the graph so the user can choose the area that will be integrated between the curves collected from the data and the adjustable line.

I was unable to find anything in androidplot that might allow me to do this, I'm fine with switching graphing libraries if that is what is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking into `Path`. That is probably the easiest class to use.

```
class Graph extends View {
    Graph(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // ... Init paints
    }

    @Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

        // Draw Y-axis
        canvas.drawLine(axisOffset, axisOffset, axisOffset, canvasHeight-axisOffset, paint);
        // Draw X-axis
        canvas.drawLine(axisOffset, canvasHeight-axisOffset, canvasWidth-axisOffset, canvasHeight-axisOffset, paint);
        canvas.drawPath(new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), mPath, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    Path mPath = new Path(); // your open path
    float canvasWidth = 1.0f;
    float canvasHeight= 1.0f;
    float axisOffset = 0.1f; // The offset from the border of the canvas

    public void registerDataPlot(int xCoord, int yCoord) {
        // You need to convert the plot data to a location on the canvas
        // Just find the percent value from the base of the axis
        float x = xCoord / (canvasWidth - (2*axisOffset));
        float y = yCoord / (canvasHeight - (2*axisOffset));
        mPath.lineTo(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Are you suggesting overlaying with path? The problem is, how do I coordinate the position of the path line with a corresponding area on the chart being draw to my view? The number of points on my chart depends on the resolution of the image scanned, and the size of the chart is dependent on the resolution and screen orientation.

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer with how you plot the data. Resolution is simply based on how often you call `registerDataPlot(int, int);`

Comment: Do you mean mPath.lineTo(x,y);?

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a transparent fullscreen canvas drawn overtop my graph activity view, can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: That's about the jist. Just add the graph view to where ever you need it. Then when you get data, call `registerDataPlot(int, int);`. If you need to move the graph, then create an offset variable and translate the canvas by that offset. If you do that however, I would translate, draw the path, then draw the axis.